# How to link to a DLL deployed through Click Once

Tags: c#, dll, clickonce

My program must integrate with some third party application deployed through ClickOnce. To facilitate the process, the maker of that application provides a .NET DLL that I can reference in my program. That DLL is shipped with their application and is located in the same folder as their executable. If I understand correctly, there is no way to predict where a ClickOnce application will be installed. What would be the best strategy to link that DLL at runtime if I don't know in advance in which folder it will be located?

Comment: if it was a GAC assembly then no problem

Comment: You could search for the directory using components from System.IO and then use System.Reflection.Assembly which gives you the option of loading a DLL from a file path.

I would also recommend looking into using Microsoft's MEF. This has been designed help build applications using 'plugin' DLLs imported at runtime.

Comment: Maybe you can just take the dll and distribute a copy of it with your program...depends on the method of integration.

Comment: @T McKeown - According to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265414/clickonce-and-gac, ClickOnce cannot install stuff in GAC.

Comment: @Darren - The maker of that application wants to control what's installed on the client machine. That why they moved to ClickOnce. If I ship the dll myself, they'll have to coordinate with me when they update their software, which is not desirable for anyone.

Comment: @daniellepelley - Performing a brute search on c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\... is something I thought about but I'm looking for a cleaner solution, if possible. Thanks for mentioning MEF. It won't help me with this problem but it sure looks interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have the vendor create a registry key either during installation or on-first-startup that points to the current app location.  I know it's not pretty but it's a solid method to ensure you can locate the app and updates don't leave you pointing to a non-existent app.

I use this method with my click-once deployment to point to both the app directory and the data directory.

Just thought of another optoin... Could you get the dll directly from the deployment point?  My click-once deployment point has the .application file along with all the assemblies.  The problem here is that you need to know the latest version to find the correct assembly.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because, after discussing the matter with the vendor, they ended up writing the assembly location in the registry like you suggested. Even if it ain't pretty, it seems to be the easiest solution for everyone.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had found a better way to do this too but sometimes the best solution is not always clean. Just remember that when a new version of their click-once app is installed (auto-updated) then the location changes.  That's why they need to update the reg entry 'on first start up' that fires after updates and is an application setting they can poll in click-once.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In your EXE project for ClickOnce,

1) Add this DLL as "Content" (You set this in the build type).
2) In the "Application Files..." for Click Once, locate the entry for the newly added DLL add set the Publish Status to "Include" and not "Include (Auto)".

The next time you publish the click once, the DLL will be placed in the same folder as your EXE.